# HTML tag is being stripped from string

Tags: java, android, string

```
<string name="codename"><b>Codename:</b></string>

strCode.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.codename)) + " " + strVersionName[inPrefConv]);
```

The `codename` string is not being set to `BOLD`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a screenshot (and, if possible, highlight where exactly is the problem). Also, what is `strCode`? A `TextView`?

Comment: Yes `strCode`is a text view. I will post screenshot for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, you can specify the entry to be unformatted

```
<string name="codename" formatted="false"><b>Codename:</b></string>
```

Also, use this to make sure that the `strVersionName[inPrefConv]` actually is part of the HTML result:

```
strCode.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.codename) + " " + strVersionName[inPrefConv]));
```

However, there is another way which is preferable to use:

In your XML, specify the entry to be unformatted and with a `%s` variable in it

```
<string name="codename" formatted="false"><b>Codename:</b> %s</string>
```

Then use `getString` with an extra parameter:

```
strCode.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.codename, strVersionName[inPrefConv]));
```

Comment: After the `+` it's a array I am retrieving. The `strVersionName[inPrefConv]` is not part of the string.

Comment: @SiKni8 I assumed `strVersionName` was an array of Strings, since you get an **index in the array** with `strVersionName[inPrefConv]`

Comment: @SiKni8 Try this code, then update your question with more details if this does not work.

Comment: I tried the updated code but it's still not bold :/ I did exactly as you posted. What information do you need? Works fine through XML but in Java code it just displays a plain text string.